# Runtime error occurs what is the problem?

Tags: c++, syntax-error

i am trying to find the average but this could not resolve. This code showing me 'runtime erorr' kindly help me my code is here:

```
cin >> n;

    while (n > 100 || n <= 0)
    {
        cout << "Error! number should in range of (1 to 100)." << endl;
        cout << "Enter the number again: ";
        cin >> n;
    }
```

Comment: What is `n` and where is it defined? See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then post the complete code, the input you enter, and the exact error message that you are getting.

Comment: Runtime error does not seem to be raised from this code snippet...

Comment: If this is about a runtime error, why is your question tagged with "syntax error"?

Answer (score -1):

I do not understand what is 'n' standing for. I found some problems with your script. First of all u should define the 'n'. Secondly, it's better not to use the loop for checking.
Thirdly, i suggest u to use this code":

```
int n;
cin>>n;
if(n>100 && n<0)
{
   cout << "Error! number should in range of (1 to 100)." << endl;
   cout << "Enter the number again: ";
   cin >> n;
}
```